# Next Sentence Prediction for 5 sentences using BERT

Tags: natural-language-processing, recurrent-neural-networks, bert

I am given a dataset in which each instance consisting of 5 sentences. The goal is to predict the sequence of numbers which represent the order of these sentences.

> For example, given a story:
>
> He went to the store. He found a lamp he liked. He bought the lamp.
> Jan decided to get a new lamp. Jan's lamp broke.
>
> your system needs to provide an answer in the following form:
>
> 2   3   4   1   0
>
> where the numbers correspond to the zero-based index of each sentence
> in the correctly ordered story. So "2" for "He went to the store."
> means that this sentence should come 3rd in the correctly ordered
> target story. In This particular example, this order of indices
> corresponds to the following target story:
>
> Jan's lamp broke. Jan decided to get a new lamp. He went to the store.
> He found a lamp he liked. He bought the lamp.

My initial idea is to extended the NSP algorithm used to train BERT, to 5 sentences somehow. I can't find an efficient way to go about doing so. All suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Is this a homework problem? If yes, you should tag your post with [tag:homework].

Comment: No, its for a personal project. Figured it out though: turns out its just using a custom head on the BERT model

Comment: Feel free to write a formal answer below to your own question ;)